# getting column names as integers in r data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I read data in r using read_excel which has the following column names

```
'Sales/Year' 2000 2001 2002

# read tibble
sales_tb = read_excel("sales.xlsx")
# convert tibble to data.frame
sales_df -< data.frame(sales_tb)
# part without sales column
sales <- sales_df[,-1]
rownames(sales) <- sales_df[,1]

years <- colnames(sales)
```

This gives

```
years = "X2000", "X2001" etc
```

I want to have

years = 2000, 2001, etc

as integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When we use `data.frame`, specify `check.names = FALSE` as the default option is `TRUE` and it appends non-standard column names (i.e. those starting with numbers) with 'X'

```
sales_df <- data.frame(sales_tb, check.names = FALSE)
```

The column names attribute will always be `character` class.  It would not be `integer`.  If we want to change it to integer, it should be outside

```
as.integer(colnames(sales_df))
```

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe `as.data.frame` does not change column names